# Nested columns with susy

Tags: susy-compass, compass-sass

i want to do a 3 columns layout and need nested these columns into a container.it's for a drupal theme so there are a lot of html stuff.basically the code structure look like this:

```
<section id="general">

      <div id="content-global">

       <!-- ______________________ CONTENT INNER GLOBAL _______________________ -->
        <div id="content-inner" class="page-MODELE">

        <!-- ______________________ CONTENU CENTRAL _______________________ -->
          <div id="middle-content" class="page-MODELE">

            <!--______________NODE TPL POUR PAGE.TPL CUSTOM________________ -->
<div class="node " id="node-16">
    <div class="node-inner">
        <!--______________COLONNE 1________________ -->
                <div class="colonne-1 col1_layout_3_8_3">
                        <h1 class="titre_page">Présentation du lycée</h1>

                    </div>
        <!--______________COLONNE 2________________ -->
         <!-- <pre>  </pre>-->   <!-- listage des variables du $content -->
        <div class="colonne-2 col2_layout_3_8_3">

        </div>

        <!--______________COLONNE 3________________ -->
        <div class="colonne-3 col3_layout_3_8_3">
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /node-inner -->
</div> <!-- /node-->                        </div> <!-- /#middle-content -->

      </div> <!-- /content-inner /content -->
    </section>
```

`#general` is my main container with `@include container($total-columns, $desktop, $tablet);`.
columns are into middle-content as this :

```
.col1_layout_3_8_3{
    @include at-breakpoint ($mobile){
        //@include span-columns($mobile);
    }
    @include at-breakpoint ($desktop){
        @include span-columns(3 alpha,$desktop);

    }
    @include at-breakpoint ($tablet){
        @include span-columns($tablet);
    }
}
.col2_layout_3_8_3{
    @include at-breakpoint ($mobile){
        @include span-columns($mobile);
    }
    @include at-breakpoint ($desktop){
        @include span-columns(8);
    }
    @include at-breakpoint ($tablet){
        @include span-columns($tablet);
    }
}
.col3_layout_3_8_3{
    @include at-breakpoint ($mobile){
        @include span-columns($mobile);
    }
    @include at-breakpoint ($desktop){
        @include span-columns(3);
    }
    @include at-breakpoint ($tablet){
        @include span-columns($tablet);
    }
}
```

but actually, each columns use the max width instead of values from breakpoint.
do i need to use alpha and omega ?
other thing, how can i do changing layout depending on choosing class ? before susy, i used the colonne-1 class to give the column position and the other class like col1_3_5_3 to set the size of the column..how can i do the same with susy ?

thanks

EDIT:
variables used for the grid

```
//*Réglage de la grille de Susy - approche mobile-first
$total-columns: 4;             // nombre de colonnes de la grille de base
$column-width: 3.70em;            // largeur de chaque colonnes (px,em,%)
$gutter-width: 0.75em;            // taille de la gouttière entre colonnes (px,em,%)
$grid-padding: $gutter-width;  // grid-padding equal to gutters

//Réglage du nombre de colonnes pour at-breakpoint() mixin 
// qui simplifie les media-queries
$mobile   : 4;
$tablet   : 10;
$desktop  : 14;
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you are doing, because the HTML is hard to read, and I don't know what settings you are using in the Sass. Where are the variables defined?

Comment: variables are into _variables.scss , see below

Comment: And what output are you getting?

Comment: you can see it here : http://d6sbx1.pfdev.tk/node/3

Comment: actually i get a warning about math into span-columns but i don't have this into my code..how to know which line is the error ?

Comment: it appears that if i use `@include span-columns($desktop);`,children blocks where in the flow,but if i use `@include set-container-width();` , children are overflow and doesn't inherit the parent size..

Comment: I don't see the problem on your linked demo. And yes, `set-container-width` is *only for containers* and should not be used internally.

Comment: the container (general) take 8 columns instead of 10 related to my grid settings..but the yellow block take the right number of column according to the desktop breakpoint..not strange for you ?i'm actually trying to do from the base with the ag test to undertsand the grid functionalities but it doesn't use `set-container-width`.i think it's a good base, isn't it ?

Comment: created an agtest page : http://d6sbx1.pfdev.tk/node/6 , seem to be better approach,but footer doesn't want to take container width with the mixin,i do using `clear:both` instead,not logical...

Comment: is it normal that with nested class the grid is more difficult to set it up than separate css class coding ? the inheritance not to work the same.

Comment: i'm facing a problem that i can't fix, on http://d6sbx1.pfdev.tk/node/3 and http://d6sbx1.pfdev.tk/node/5 , width doesn't use the maximum.